Non gate based error mitigation on qiskit
I am attempting to measure the expectation value of a product state using qiskit_ibm_runtime.EstimatorV2. There are no gates in the circuits. What options/techniques should I use to mitigate the measurement errors? Zero Noise Extrapolation (ZNE) is not relevant as there are no gates. I am using optimization_level=3 when constructing the ISA circuits as advised here, which incorporates dynamical decoupling as I understand.
Are there any other techniques I should utilise to minimise the measurement errors?
While this task might sound trivial, what I am trying to achieve here is to try to separate errors from measurements from the errors from gates. To provide further context, I am trying to measure the energy of a Hartree Fock state for a given Hamiltonian to see whether I can get close to the reference energy, before applying a variational ansatz to incorporate electronic correlation.

I think you should use the measure_mitigation and enable_measure from the available options for EstimatorV2. Here's how you can do this:
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import QiskitRuntimeService
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import EstimatorV2 as Estimator
 
service = QiskitRuntimeService()
backend = service.least_busy(operational=True, simulator=False)
 
estimator = Estimator(backend)
options = estimator.options

# Turn on measurement error mitigation.
options.resilience.measure_mitigation = True 

# Turn on the twirling of measurements.
options.twirling.enable_measure = True

But keep in mind that the more mitigation methods you use in your circuit the more time qiskit will take to generate the expectation values (because it will need to generate more samples).
